# Punctuation mark for the odd, weird or unusual

Tags: punctuation

I have been writing a game monography where I put together the analysis of several computer games. In order to help readers, I decided to use some punctuation marks to bring their attention to specific games. So, for instance, I decided to put a star (or just an asterisk, *, in ASCII) on the games that I consider are good, two stars (**) on games that are really good and so on. I think this is consistent on how things are rated using stars.

Now, every now and then I review a game that is really weird or unusual, even if it is not good at all. So I wanted to also bring the readers' attention to these oddities by using a different punctuation mark on these games titles. So far I have been using the tilde (~), but this is not consistent with the usual usage of this symbol.

After searching for a while I have been unable to find a symbol that is used on this sense. Probably it doesn't even exist. So my question is, is there any symbol that is used on this context? if not, what is the best way to get around it? Should I use another well known symbol by indicating what its usage mean in the text? Should I use a not widely used symbol to avoid confusing people?

Comment: You can use the cross symbol to show the wierd or unusual games : (x) Unusal game.

Comment: Are you using multiple tildes? And in combination with stars?

Comment: ☝ could be "note this"

Comment: Depending on how this text will be presented, maybe you could use some sort of font style change such as a different colour or font?

Comment: Wow, way to overthink this. Colors? Fonts? ☝s? How about using a simple question mark.

Comment: Not an answer but how about a kerned *Aw*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are thinking of a *games* context, you may wish to look at [chess notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_annotation_symbols), in which "?" is a mistake, "?!" dubious and "!?" interesting.

Whatever you use, you should explain all your notation unless it's standard or totally obvious.

Comment: Also (!) for surprising, ingenious or plain interesting.

Comment: And perhaps even expanding chess notation a bit to include **‽**, the [interrobang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang)?

Comment: Chess notation was the first thing that came to my mind too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't know this notation. I think !? is a good choice for it. I have tried to use the interrobang, but it doesn't look too well.

Comment: @terdon, indeed, there's a whole scale of symbols. My chess-losing days are 20 years behind me, but my half-recollection of the notation left me thinking it would be a good fit.  In fact, I think it should be more widely used.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Double Dagger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dagger_%28typography%29) would be a good choice. It can be used to indicate a foot-note, and it's an uncommon enough symbol (in my experience anyway), that it would probably grab attention as a weird little thing. As an example of a list of games:

> Shoot and Blast Stuff
>
> Empires an' Armies
>
> Dr. Smith's Zany Adventures in Veterinarian Proctology ‡
>
> Jump between a bunch of platforms and grab shiny stuff
>
> ---
>
> ‡ - Unusual game.

While it's true that the Wikipedia article say "A third footnote employs the double dagger", I think that if you're not writing a formal paper and you want an unusual symbol, it would be OK to use it in this context.

I don't think there is any standard English typographical symbol to indicate that something is weird or unusual, so using an unusual footnote symbol and then actually including a footnote explaining the symbol might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cross symbol to show the weird or unusual games : (x) Unusual game,
1) * : good game , 2) **- excellent games .

You can also use three asterisk signs * to show that a game is weird or unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use whatever you prefer to show this. You might like one of these: http://mentalfloss.com/article/12710/13-little-known-punctuation-marks-we-should-be-using.

Alternatively, you could adhere to the order of typographical symbols usually used in footnotes (seeing as the first of these is the asterisk, which you are using first, though as a rating device): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(typography)

Personally, I've always liked "?!" to show surprise in informal texts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like these are things that make you go *hmmm?*  A quizzical reaction.

Why not just a **?** These games are a bit of a puzzlement, and stranger ones can get multiple **???s**

If you wanted a bit more esoteric, you could use the Spanish language inverted **¿**

As in any system that uses symbols, I would recommend that you include a key at the outset, defining both your symbols and the range you use.

Answer (score -1):

I would use **punctuation marks** to "indicate the structure and organization of written language, as well as intonation and pauses to be observed when reading aloud", leaving all the other functions to **typographical symbols**.

For your reviews you may use some weird-looking character, for example, ٭ or ۝ or  ۞ or ۩.

**EDIT**: Now that's *weird*… May anyone who downvoted my answer please stand up and kindly explain the reason for the downvote? I take it the downvote has been used to encourage me to improve the answer—so can you please let me know what's wrong with it now? Thanks.

Comment: Do those characters have names?

Comment: Yes: ٭ is an Five Pointed Star (Arabic); ۝ — End of Ayah (Arabic); ۩ — Place of Sajdah (Arabic); ۞ — Start Of Rub El Hizb (Arabic).

Comment: I'm guessing the Five Pointed Star is used the same as an asterisk? End of Aya and Start Of Rub El Hizb sound like they would be used to mark the begining or end of a specific type of block of text. Place of Sajdah... Maybe some kind of placeholder?

Comment: Actually, these may be a poor choice due to some special meaning they may already have. Then these — ⌂, ☼, ђ, ҳ — may be safer (or any other character (desirably Unicode) which tends to look weird to the target audience).